# CSS Flex One Large Div on the left and two small divs on the right

Tags: css, flexbox

I know I can easily achieve this kind of layout using the css `float` which is the current way I have the divs have the layout right now. But, I am trying to recode it and change it to flex alignment.

Here is my markup:

```html
<div id="the-posts">
    <div class="the-post-inner">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="image" style="background-image: url(https://www.dike.lib.ia.us/images/sample-1.jpg/image);"></div>
            <div class="content"><h2>Post 1</h2></div>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
            <div class="image" style="background-image: url(https://www.dike.lib.ia.us/images/sample-1.jpg/image);"></div>
            <div class="content"><h2>Post 2</h2></div>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
            <div class="image" style="background-image: url(https://www.dike.lib.ia.us/images/sample-1.jpg/image);"></div>
            <div class="content"><h2>Post 3</h2></div>
        </a>        
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```css
.the-post-inner {
    clear: both;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
    align-content: flex-start;
}

.the-post-inner a {
    margin-bottom: 4%;
}

.the-post-inner a .image {
      padding-bottom: 60%;
}

.the-post-inner a .content {
      padding: 20px;
}

.the-post-inner a .content h2 {
      margin: 0;
}

.the-post-inner a:first-child {
    flex: 0 0 60%;
    margin-right: 4%;
}

.the-post-inner a:not(:first-child) {
    margin-right: 0;
    flex: 0 0 36%;
    align-self: flex-start;

    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
```

I tried several codes based on the answers in other posts but I can't seem to make this work.

Thanks in advance for the suggestions.

EDIT:

I was wondering if there is a way to achieve this without changing the current markup which is not to separate the left post in another div and the right posts in another container.

https://jsfiddle.net/pextb1of/

Comment: see https://jsfiddle.net/roq1v94m/ is this the requirement? if that's fine, will convert to an answer..

Answer (score 1):

I just put some fix. maybe will help you.

```css
.the-post-inner {
    clear: both;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
    align-content: flex-start;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

a {
    /*border: 1px solid #000;*/
    margin-bottom: 4%;
    /*padding: 20px;*/
}

.the-post-inner {
    flex: 0 0 60%;
    margin-right: 4%;
}

.sec-inner {
    margin-right: 0;
    flex: 0 0 36%;
    align-self: flex-start;
    flex-direction: column;

    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    display: flex;
}



#the-posts{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div id="the-posts">
    <div class="the-post-inner">
        <a href="#">Post 1</a>
        
    </div>
    <div class="sec-inner">
        <a href="#">Post 2</a> 
        <a href="#">Post 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestions. I forgot to mention that I am aware of this workaround which is to separate the left and right posts in two separate divs. I could easily solve my issue with this but I am wondering if there is a way to achieve my desired layout without changing my markup.